# Swift UIScrollView setZoomScale Zooming To Wrong Point

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a zoomable `UIImageView` within a `UIScrollView`. If a user double taps on the image, the `UIScrollView` will zoom in until the image fills the screen. I have that zoom scale set in the code. This part of the code works great. Here is the code:

```
func scrollViewDoubleTapped(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // Zoom into the zoom scale if currently at min zoom, else zoom to min zoom
    if (scrollView.zoomScale == scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(zoomScale, animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The problem comes if I want to zoom into the specified zoom scale right when the view is loaded. When I attempt this zooming, the offset is incorrect. I have `println` within the function `scrollViewDidEndZooming` to help show me the offset, scale, and anchor point.

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView!, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    println("did end zooming with scale: \(scale)")
    println("offset: \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
    println("anchor point: \(scrollView.layer.anchorPoint)")
}
```

When I attempt to zoom after the view is loaded, I get the values:

```
did end zooming with scale: 2.27556
offset: (490.0, -0.0)
anchor point: (0.5, 0.5)
```

Which has the incorrect y offset. When I double tap on the image to zoom in I get:

```
did end zooming with scale: 2.27556
offset: (490.0, 653.0)
anchor point: (0.5, 0.5)
```

Would anyone be able to help me figure out why I'm having the issues zooming when the view is loaded. I do the call from the `viewDidAppear` function.